# How to parse python b' before dict

Tags: python, json, response

How to access id or nickname value with python3:

```
response._content = b'{"id":44564,"nickname":'Demo'}
```

Comment: You don't have a dict. You have a byte string containing a JSON value.

Comment: @chepner actually, it does not contain valid JSON, single quotes around the `'Demo'`

Comment: Good point, but it's still a string, not a dict :)

Comment: What is `response`, and why are you accessing an attribute with a "don't-touch-me" underscore on it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It doesn't even match up the single quotes, so it's not a syntactically legal line of Python (it's a `bytes` literal until the second `'`, then a reference to a `Demo` variable, then an unterminated `str` literal).

Comment: I rolled back Jay's edit because it made meaningful changes syntactically (switching single to double quotes, adding additional quotes). The OP can fix to what they actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to read in a Json string and convert it to a dict, e.g.:

```
import json

# response._content = b'{"id":44564,"nickname":"Demo"}'

data = json.loads(response._content.decode('utf-8'))

# data = {'id': 44564, 'nickname': 'Demo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a byte string that includes JSON as stated above. Another way to look at it is that is a dict definition (i.e python code). You can use eval for that:

```
foo = eval( b'{"id":44564,"nickname":"Demo"}')
foo['nickname']
```

Probably this is not the preferred or secure way to do it because eval is considered dangerous

https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html